# White space in a theorem beginning with a list

Tags: spacing, lists, theorems, enumitem, amsthm

This question is about how to get rid of the white space in a theorem beginning with a list between the theorem caption and the first item:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item First item.
            \item Second item.
            \item Third item.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The behavior is described in the `amsthm` documentation:

> [image]

The resulting output looks the way I want it (here I included some other customizations to produce an output which is close to what I want to use in my actual document):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\firstitem}{\hangindent\leftmargini
    \textup{(\romannumeral1)}\hspace{\labelsep}\ignorespaces}

\setlist[enumerate]{label=\textup{(\roman{*})},itemsep=0pt,topsep=\smallskipamount}

\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}
        \firstitem First item with more than one line. This is some blindtext to include a line break.
        \begin{enumerate}
            \setcounter{enumi}{1}
            \item Second item.
            \item Third item.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However I don't really find this approach acceptable for the following reasons:

- It breaks my work flow to type the item and set the counter manually.
- It does not easily allow for global customization of lists, changing from arabic numbering to roman numbering for example, or changing the `itemsep`.
- It does not without further work allow to `\label` the first list item in order to `\ref` it in the text.

So are there any solutions to obtain desirable formatting and without any of the negative side effects just described?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the key `wide=0pt`.  I added some other formatting, in particular, I think the enumerate labels should be upshape and the vertical skip between items should be smaller – but it's only my point of view.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newlist{thmenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[thmenumerate, 1]{label=(\roman*), itemsep=0pt, widest=(iii), font=\upshape}

\begin{document}

    \begin{theorem}
        \begin{thmenumerate}[wide=-0.5pt, leftmargin=*, labelsep=0em]
            \item \mbox{}\hspace*{-1em}First item with more than one line. This is some blindtext to include a line break.
        \end{thmenumerate}
        \begin{thmenumerate}[resume, topsep = 0pt, align = right]
            \item Second item. Second item. Second item. Second item. Second item. Second item. Second item. Second item.
            \item Third item.
        \end{thmenumerate}
    \end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Another code to fulfil your requirements*:

I define in the preamble a `thmenumerate` list, and one uses the `resume` key after rhe first item which has a different formatting:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newlist{thmenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[thmenumerate, 1]{label = (\roman*), itemsep = 0pt, font=\upshape}

\begin{document}

    \begin{theorem}
        \begin{thmenumerate}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, widest=(iii), labelsep=-0.5em]
            \item First item with more than one line. This is some blindtext to include a line break. 
        \end{thmenumerate}
        \begin{thmenumerate}[resume*, topsep = 0pt ]
            \item Second item. Second item. Second item. Second item. Second item. Second item. Second item. Second item.
            \item Third item.
        \end{thmenumerate}
    \end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Perhaps it did not become clear from my question but I only want to delete the space in front of the very first item in order to match the appearance of the official `amsthm` solution. In particular the next items should be indented as in a default list. I edited the question accordingly. I apologize for the misunderstanding.

Comment: And the hanging indent for multiline items contents?

Comment: Yes, this should be included. I included an example in my question which produces an output that is very close to what I want to use in my actual document. And perhaps the needed code shows that it is not practical to use a non-automated approach to get it.

Comment: The idea with `resume` is good, because it allows the usage of `\label` (as opposed to my ad hoc solution in the question). But  the indent of the first item is not yet correct (and I don't know how to fix that).

Comment: Could you explain in detail what you'd like to have?

Comment: The indent of the first enum label w.r.t. ‘Theorem 1.’ or the  label sep between item label and the beginning of the item contents?

Comment: Oh yes! I'll try to think of a solution a little later.

Comment: @JohnDorian: I've posted a solution. Is it OK?

Comment: @Bernhard I tried to play around with your solution to reproduce exactly my own layout but I did not succeed. Anyway your solution clearly looks better than the one with the default white space so it is certainly helpful to me. If you don't mind, I will upvote but leave the question open for a while to wait for other suggestions. One other thing I am not yet entirely happy with is the fact that I have to make sure manually to start two instances of `thmenumerate` whenever a theorem begins with an enumeration.

Comment: @JohnDorian: I've made some modifications to the first code, which results, I think, in something closer to your requirements. Also, I thought one might incorporate the first instance of the thmenumerate environment into the definition of this environment by making the first item an argument of the environment.